# Can you resize an image in a flutter_native_splash?

Tags: flutter

I am using the package mentioned in the title, but I do not have expected results.
[image]

As you can see, the image does not occupy all the space. and here the .yaml file

```
flutter_native_splash: 
  color: 00ff00
  image: assets/splash_screenrick.png
```

By the way, I use the color because if I delete it, it marks an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resize image in pub package "flutter\_native\_splash"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907278/how-can-i-resize-image-in-pub-package-flutter-native-splash)

Comment: should I close the question or delete it? Well, it didn't solve it for me, but from what I see, that package doesn't allow you to enlarge images.

Comment: actually I'm unsure about it, since apparently the thread I linked doesn't contain a concrete solution to your problem. Maybe your question will draft the attention of someone who knows how to solve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // Show splash screen for 2 seconds
  runApp(
    SizedBox(
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/image1.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  );
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  // Then, start the app
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Without any package. This also helps for when you have a splash screen with animations.